# 400 Bad request on Heroku, using Node.js and Python Flask

Tags: express, flask, heroku, proxy

I'm working on a web application and facing an issue with its deployment on Heroku. I'm getting a 400 bad request.

```
flask app
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="frontend/  ", static_url_path="")
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)


@app.route("/", defaults={"path": ""})
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def index(path):
    if path != "" and path != "api/search":
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path)
    else:
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, "index.html")


@app.route("/api/get_data", methods=['GET', ['POST']])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def get_data():
    try:
        df = pandas.read_csv('final_perfume_data_with_prices.csv',
                             encoding='utf8', encoding_errors="ignore")
        records = df.to_json(orient='records')
        return jsonify(records)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return jsonify({'error': 'An error occurred processing your request'}), 500

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5001))
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

```
node.cjs:

const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const backendUrl =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        ? "my_app"
        : "http://127.0.0.1:5001";

// app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));

app.use(
    "/api",
    createProxyMiddleware({
        target: backendUrl,
        changeOrigin: true,
        onError: (err, req, res) => {
            console.error(`Error in proxy middleware: ${err.message}`);
            res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
        },
    })
);
// All other requests serve the frontend index.html
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send("400 Bad server request");
});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    if (res.status) {
        console.log("Error in handling request");
    }
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

```
my app.tsx  

async function fetchData() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("/api/get_data");
            setListOfFragrances(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        }
    }
```

So what i have done is made flask serve as an api endpoint that returns a json. While i have a node.js act as both frontend and backend to proxy to the flask server. I've verified that all environment variables are correctly set in Heroku.  CORS is configured properly in the Flask app. Checked Heroku logs and am still unsure